# JPA Query for Column, Column has @Embedded Object

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm writing JPA query and I have a Entity in side that Entity I have @Embedded Object, If I want to retrieve data based on the field in side @Embedded Object Can I write a JPA query instead of Named query?

Here is My Object structure :

```
    public class MyEntity {
      private String field1;
      private String field2;
      @Embedded
      private InnerEntity;
    }  

  @Embeddable
  public class InnerEntity {
   private String field3;
   private String field4
}
```

Now I have to write a JPA query with field3 like how we do directly with field name (findByField1(value));

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<MyEntity> root = cq.from(MyEntity.class);

Predicate p = cb.equal(root.get("InnerEntity").get("field3"), 100);

cq.multiselect(root.get("field1").alias("field1"),                
             root.get("InnerEntity").get("field3").alias("field3Alias));

List<Tuple> tt = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```